# Difference between malloc(sizeof(ptr)) and malloc(sizeof(ptr*))?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to know what is the difference between these two lines :

```
 queue* f=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
```

```
 queue* f=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue*));
```

Here's the definition of queue:

```
typedef struct queue
{
    int arr[N];
    int tail;
}queue;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The supposed "duplicate" is about casting, but the key issue here is the size.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is, but the first answer explains why you in this case should not use neither form, but instead `malloc(sizeof *f)`

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yeah, I suspect someone saw that the other question was associated because I linked it in my answer, but it's not a duplicate at all.

Comment: But ok, here you have a perfect dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363427/what-is-the-difference-between-mallocsizeofint-and-mallocsizeofint

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between malloc(sizeof(int)) and malloc(sizeof(int\*))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363427/what-is-the-difference-between-mallocsizeofint-and-mallocsizeofint)

Comment: why did you not accepted the answer of @ShadowRanger ? (may be you just forgot to do)

Comment: @bruno because at that time i didn't have enough points to give him the best answer, but now i do, thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that the second line is wrong; it allocates enough space to store a *pointer* to a `queue`, not a `queue` itself, but it's assigned to a type that assumes it points to enough space for a whole `queue`.

[Neither one requires a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/3646960), so the correct form is:

```
queue *f = malloc(sizeof(queue));
```

To be even safer, don't refer to the type itself, refer to the variable you're assigning to, to avoid repeating the type (potentially causing maintenance problems if the type is changed); this also means [`sizeof` doesn't need parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13120473/364696):

```
queue *f = malloc(sizeof *f);
```

Comment: `sizeof` requires parentheses if the operand is a type name like `int` or a typedef name like `queue`.

Comment: @JohnBode: Ah, you're right. I'm so used to using the `*f` form I forgot the rule for naming the type itself. Fixed, and linked to the question that covers the rule.